# rm -rf /base-dir-path/*/work isn't the same as /base-dir-path/*/*/work

Tags: shell, unix, wildcard, solaris, tcsh

If I want to delete all subdirectories with a given name from a given root directory in linux/unix, you would think that you could just issue a command like:

```
rm -rf /base-dir-path/*/work
```

However, the above command will only go 1 directory deep when searching for any subdirectories named 'work'. To achieve what I want, I end up repeating the same command with an extra '*/' until the rm returns 'rm: No match.', EG:

```
rm -rf /base-dir-path/*/*/*/work
```

Is there a way to get commands like `rm` to match `/` in its wildcard search so that I only have to issue a single wildcard `*` character?

Comment: I generally use tcsh, here's the version printout:
tcsh 6.12.00 (Astron) 2002-07-23 (sparc-sun-solaris)

Comment: anyhow, questions about a non-POSIX shell need to *specifically* name that shell. When you ask a question just tagged "shell", folks are going to assume it's a POSIX sh compliant / derivative one.

Comment: To be clear, by the way -- on UNIX (unlike Windows), it's not the command (like `rm`) that does any matching at all; the shell performs glob expansion itself, and passes the list of resulting names to the underlying command; the command has no part in it, and in fact has no way of knowing that the user entered a glob expression rather than an explicit list of names.

Comment: That's actually a really useful tidbit of information :)

Comment: Fixed the tags... lied is a harsh way of describing when somebody misrepresents their issue (lied implies intent, mistakes are unintentional). To be clear... I do use Bash on RHEL and tcsh on SunOS... I only mentioned the tcsh above because, generally speaking, when the commands work there they work everywhere else.

Comment: Not a safe assumption, sadly. POSIX sh is the baseline that most other modern shells (excluding zsh, fish, and csh-family) are compatible with; csh, however, is very much not compliant with POSIX sh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On tcsh 6.18.00 or newer:

```
set globstar
rm -rf /base-path/path/**/work
```

On bash 4.0 or newer:

```
shopt -s globstar
rm -rf /base-dir/path/**/work
```

On ksh:

```
set -o globstar # or set -G
rm -rf /base-dir/path/**/work
```

On zsh:

```
rm -rf /base-dir/path/**/work
```

---

Alternately, with a `find` compliant with the 2006 revision of POSIX:

```
find /base-dir/path -type d -name work -exec rm -rf -- '{}' +
```

---

If you don't have a `find` with `-exec ... {} +`, then you likely don't have an `xargs -0` either, and need to do this the inefficient way to be safe:

```
find /base-dir/path -type d -name work -exec rm -rf -- '{}' ';'
```

Comment: The bash version on the RHEL I use is 3.2.25 :| ... the more verbose find command is what I was trying to avoid but I guess I'll just have to get more comfortable with it unless somebody else has another suggestion

Comment: If anyone reads this, the real answer to my question is in Charles Duffy's comment to the original post in his explanation about how global expansion is performed relative to the shell command...

Comment: @user3462694 Note that using `**` will also work in `tcsh`. You will need to use `set globstar` (default off). You can also use `***` to descend into symlinks. You will need tcsh 6.18.00 from Jan. 2012 for this.